# Sum of the Infinite Power Series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I need to calculate the sum of the infinite power series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k(k+1)k}{3e^2k!}$$

I was thinking of using the exponential function power series expansion formula

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

but still not sure how to deal with the initial expression to make use of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

For $ k\ge 2 $,  Replace $(k+1)k $ by

$$k(k-1)+2k$$

to get
$$\frac{2^kk(k+1)}{k!}=4\Bigl(\frac{2^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}+\frac{2^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\Bigr)$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k(k+1)k}{3e^2k!}&=\frac{1}{3e^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k(k+1)k}{k!}\\&=\frac{1}{3e^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k(k^2+k)}{k!}\\&=\frac{1}{3e^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^kk^2}{k!}+\frac{1}{3e^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^kk}{k!}\end{align}

where the Maclaurin expansion of $e^2$ is

$$e^2=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{k!}$$

therefore

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^kk^2}{k!}=6\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{k!}=6e^2$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^kk}{k!}=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{k!}=2e^2$$

thus

\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k(k+1)k}{3e^2k!}&=\frac{1}{3e^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^kk^2}{k!}+\frac{1}{3e^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^kk}{k!}\\&=
\frac{1}{3e^2}6e^2+\frac{1}{3e^2}2e^2\\&=
2+\frac23\\&=
\frac{8}{3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the MacLaurin series of $x^2 \exp(x)$?